# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el contador defina todos los números?

Tags: python, if, while

```
Edad_persona=int(input("Ingresar la edad:"))

Cont=0

Cont1=0

Sum=0

Sum1=0


while Edad_persona!=999:

     Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))
     if Edad_persona>18 and Edad_persona<999:
         Cont=Cont+1
         Sum=Sum+Edad_persona
     if Edad_persona<18:
         Cont1=Cont1+1
         Sum1=Sum1+Edad_persona

print("Los menores son:" ,Cont1)

print("Los mayores son:" ,Cont)

print("El promedio es de:" ,(((Sum1)+Sum)/(Cont+Cont1)))
```

El `contador1` al final de todo me muestra la cantidad de edades, pero con un valor menos, ¿Cómo puedo incluir el valor de arriba de todo?, ósea el primer `Edad_Persona`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tratar de simular la estuctura do-while loop de esta forma:

```
while True:
  //operaciones
  if (condición para terminar el loop):
    break
```

De esta forma, puedes incorporar dentro del loop todas las lecturas de la edad y luego calcular los resultados:

```
Cont=0
Cont1=0
Sum=0
Sum1=0
while True:

        Edad_persona=int(input("Ingrese su edad:"))

        if(Edad_persona == 999):
            break

    if Edad_persona>18 and Edad_persona<999:
            Cont=Cont+1
            Sum=Sum+Edad_persona
    if Edad_persona<18:
            Cont1=Cont1+1
            Sum1=Sum1+Edad_persona

print("Los menores son:" ,Cont1)
print("Los mayores son:" ,Cont)
print("El promedio es de:" ,(((Sum1)+Sum)/(Cont+Cont1)))
```

Ejecución:

```
Ingrese su edad:10
Ingrese su edad:5
Ingrese su edad:20
Ingrese su edad:40
Ingrese su edad:10
Ingrese su edad:999
('Los menores son:', 3)
('Los mayores son:', 2)
('El promedio es de:', 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más simple usando tu misma idea es mover el `input` al final del `while`, con esto no necesitas tocar nada más ni recurrir a un condicional extra:

```
cont_men = 0
cont_may = 0
sum_men = 0
sum_may = 0

edad_persona = int(input("Ingrese su edad: "))
while edad_persona != 999:
    if edad_persona >= 18:
        cont_may += 1
        sum_may += edad_persona
    else:
        cont_men += 1
        sum_men += edad_persona 
    edad_persona = int(input("Ingrese su edad: "))

print("Los menores son:" , cont_may)
print("Los mayores son:" , cont_men)
print("El promedio es de:", (sum_may + sum_men) / (cont_may + cont_men))
```

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- No uses dos `if`, esto es ineficiente y no es necesario en tu caso. Si se cumple una de las condiciones sabemos que la otra no lo va a hacer, por lo tanto no tiene sentido comprobarla. Usa una construcción de tipo  `if-elif-else` en su lugar.
- Por convención los nombres de variables no deben empezar con mayúscula, esto se reserva para las clases o para las "constantes" (todo el nombre en mayúscula).
- En tu código te dejas fuera al los que tienen 18 años de ambas categorías. En mi caso los he incluido en la primera (con 18 años o más).
- Ten en cuanta que si no vas a calcular la media de cada rango no necesitas dos variables para la suma, con una basta.

En tu caso no validas la  entrada del usuario, pudiendo este ingresar números negativos o edades claramente erróneas como 700 años. Si lo deseas puedes validar esto en la misma construcción:

```
cont_men = 0
cont_may = 0
sum_men = 0
sum_may = 0

edad_persona = int(input("Ingrese su edad: "))
while edad_persona != 999:
    if 18 <= edad_persona < 150:
        cont_may += 1
        sum_may += edad_persona
    elif 0 < edad_persona < 18:
        cont_men += 1
        sum_men += edad_persona
    else:
        print("La edad ingresada no es válida (0 < edad < 150)"
    edad_persona = int(input("Ingrese su edad: "))

print("Los menores son:" , cont_may)
print("Los mayores son:" , cont_men)
print("El promedio es de:", (sum_may + sum_men) / (cont_may + cont_men))
```